# Not declared in this scope error for function

Tags: c++, function, scope, declare

I'm trying to define a function in a class and then use it in a .cpp program. I have declared the function above main and can't figure out why I'm getting a not declared in scope error.

Error from g++: "error: ‘convert’ was not declared in this scope"

Thanks in advance.

A.h:

```
class A
{
    public:

        int convert(char bcd);

};
```

program.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int A::convert(char b)
{
    return b*5;
}

int main(){

    char myword = '27'; 
    char cc = convert(myword); //scope error here
    cout << "Number is: " << cc << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `convert` belongs to an `A`. You are asking for a free `convert` function.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself is because you don't have any "free function" defined by the name `convert()` that's in any scope directly accessible from the scope in which you try to call it. You have one that's a member method ("function") of `class A`, but none defined outside of that class. So yes you have a "function" named `convert()` defined, but it's not accessible in the scope in which you're trying to call it. You'll have to add something to tell the compiler where to find this "`convert()`" function you're trying to call. There are a few ways to do that:

1. For a nonstatic class member function (normally called a "method" when it's part of a class), you'll first need an object of that class's type in order to call the method.
2. For class static member functions (normally called "static methods"), you can call it using a object of that type in order to resolve the scope, or since it's a static method, you can use the class's name (along with the `::` scope resolution operator) to resolve the scope.
3. If you have a "free function" that's defined in a separate namespace that doesn't encompass the scope in which you're trying to call the function, you'll need to use either the `::` scope resolution operator (e.g. "`namespaceName::functionName()`"), or else use the "`using`" keyword to bring that function's name into the current scope.

Since you're asking about a class member method, I'll ignore #3 above in the following discussion....

Will you have an instance of `class A`? If so, say you call it "fred", then you could call `fred.convert(myword);`. But `A::convert()` doesn't use any member data of `class A`, so perhaps you want it to be a static member method (i.e. it can be called even without an object of the class's type), in which you'd need to declare the method as `static`, and when you call it, use "`A::convert(myword);`".

Here's an example of creating an instance of `class A` and invoking method `A::convert()` on it:

```
===== file 'A.h' =====
class A
{
    public:
        int convert(char bcd);
};

===== file 'program.cpp' =====
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int A::convert(char b)
{
    return b*5;
}

int main()
{
    char myword = '27';
    A fred; // create an instance of class A named "fred"
    char cc = fred.convert(myword);
    cout << "Number is: " << cc << endl;
}
```

Here's an example where `A::convert()` is a static member method, and an instance of the class is not required in order to call the method:

```
===== file 'A.h' =====
class A
{
    public:
        static int convert(char bcd); // <--- note 'static' keyword
};

===== file 'program.cpp' =====
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int A::convert(char b)
{
    return b*5;
}

int main()
{
    char myword = '27';
    A fred; // create an instance of class A named "fred"
    char cc = fred.convert(myword); // you can call convert() on an A object
    char dd = A::convert(myword); // or you can call it without an A object
    cout << "Number cc is: " << cc << endl;
    cout << "Number dd is: " << dd << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 3 things:

1. Functions
2. Class Member Methods
3. Static Class Methods

A function is a set of commands to be executed in a row. You declare them like so:

```
type function(type parameter1, type parameter2 /*etc */);
```

You define them like this:

```
type function(type parameter1, type parameter2 /*etc */) {
  // implementation...
}
```

And call them like this:

```
type myvar = function(parameter1,parameter2 /*etc */);
```

A Class method is a function that is also a member of a class. It generally uses instance data to perform some operation. You declare them like this:

```
class A
{
    public:

        type method(type parameter1, type parameter2);

};
```

define them like this:

```
type A::method(type parameter1, type parameter2)
{
    return b*5;
}
```

and call them like this:

```
A myVar;
myVar.method(parameter1,parameter2);
```

Finally, there is what @phonetagger suggested, which is is Static Class Methods. These are like regular methods, but generally don't touch instance data. Yet, they are usually related to the class in some way. You declare them like this:

```
class A
{
    public:

        static type method(type parameter1, type parameter2);

};
```

define them like this:

```
type A::method(type parameter1, type parameter2)
{
    return b*5;
}
```

and call them like this:

```
A::method(parameter1,parameter2);
```

You need to decide which one you really need and implement it properly.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense now. Thanks for your really informative answer. Helped me a lot.